# Yii подменить layout в контроллере?

Tags: yii

народ подскажите как сделать следующее в контроллере ?

```
If ($_GET['mode'] == 1 ) public $layout='//layouts/column2';
else public $layout='//layouts/column1';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете поместить код, изменяющий поле `$layout`, в ваше действие в контроллере:

```
public function actionIndex($mode)
{
    if ($mode == 1)
        $this->layout = "//layouts/column2";
    else
        $this->layout = "//layouts/column1";
    $this->render('index');
}
```